# NMinimize to ignore arguments for which function is complex valued

Tags: mathematical-optimization, complex

I'd like to minimize a pretty complicated function $f(x, y, z)$ with `NMinimize`, however for certain values of the arguments $f$ becomes complex valued, and my `NMinimize` essentially fails... Is there a way to make Mathematica only consider arguments for which the function I'm trying to minimize f is real-valued?

Comment: Use `FunctionDomain` to identify constraints that restrict the function to being real. Include these constraints in the `NMinimize`. However, a concrete example would be useful.

Comment: This is how I solve it for `NMaximize`. Assuming that I know that the maximum value that I am looking for is positive, instead of `NMaximize[f[x], x]` I use `NMaximize[With[{z = f[x]}, Re[z] DiscreteDelta[Im[z]] - Abs[Im[z]]], x]`. This turns complex values with non-zero imaginary part into negative real values, but doesn't affect real values. You can adapt this approach for `NMinimize` too.